# Build URL from HTML form

Tags: php

What is the simplest method to link to a URL from a form?

**Form example:**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="chat" method="post">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="nickname">Nickname</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control" required="required">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="age">Age</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="age" name="age" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <?php 
            for($value = 18; $value <= 100; $value++){ 
              echo('<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>');
            }
          ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio" for="gender-0">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-0" value="Female" required="required">
          Female
        </label>
        <label class="radio" for="gender-1">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-1" value="Male" required="required">
          Male
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="location">Location</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="location" name="location" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="France">France</option>
          <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
          <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
          <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
          <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
          <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
          <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="United States">United States</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="checkbox"></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="checkbox inline" for="checkbox-0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox-0" value="I agree to the Terms of Use" required="required">
          I agree to the <a href="legal.php">Terms of Use</a>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="button"></label>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit">Enter Chat</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

So how is it possible to then create a URL for example:

`start.php?nickname=Steve&age=18&gender=male&location=United%23Kingdom`

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`<form method="get">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Examples), or you can concatenate all $_POST parameters then redirect.

Comment: @user2656114 try it! Although it may not do exactly what you want, due to the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Form method to to `get` by saying `<form method="get">`

Each form field and its value will be appended to the URL as `&field=value`

`GET` And `POST` are two different methods of sending data. Be careful though, you should use `GET` only if you are not sending secure information. Data like passwords, credit card numbers, account numbers, and other confidential stuff should only be sent with `POST`. Why? Simply because that data is shown in the `URL`. `POST` is another method. The server handles POST requests, and stores all fields and their corresponding values somewhere so that you can access them on the page the form submits to.

Comment: Please bear in mind that your date is not safe just because you use `post` instead of `get`. You should also make use of SSL. Without it, still everyone between client and server can read any date -- post and get.

Comment: @GhostGambler you meant to say **data** rather than date. Please edit your comment to eliminate confusion.

Comment: Yes, I meant data. Cannot edit the comment though, as the time window which allows edits has elapsed already.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line to:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="start.php" method="get">
```

- In the `action`, you type the path and name of the page you want to post the form to. In your example that is `start.php`.
- In the `method`, you type `get` if you want the form values to be send in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people said, the `method='get'` is the best way.
But you can also create something in jquery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    window.open('start.php?'+str );
   });
});
```